# Spinner/Loader does not stop after page loading

Tags: javascript, css, loader

I found a simple spinner/loader that uses only one `div` and one `css`. When I implemented that, i found that it was not stopping. It goes on and on.... so I inserted window load script given below. still it does not stop. What am I doing wrong?
Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qzLdjq3c/5/

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.spinner').show();
    $(".spinner").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't even use jQuery (*on the left side under included libraries*) in your example. second you use `#` instead of a dot (class) selector `.`... and third, in jsFiddle, look at the left side. You already run the js on the onLoad...you can't just fire it again (i think), anyway, you are wrong at everything imaginably possible. fix what I said and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice. im new to jsfiddle.. btw which one to take... i took 1.9.1

Comment: latest I guess. depending on your project's needs. I cannot say for you.

Comment: I have observed a strange behavior. Everything was working fine as per your advice. I have corrected my original code and fiddle too. When I changed uploaded my file on a different server it doesn't work (unfortunately I cannot send link of the page) It is the same file on both the hosting space on the old hosting it works but not on the new one. What happens on the new one is... The page starts loading but the spinner is not visible and when the page it about to load, it just shows the glimpse of the spinner and it disappears and the page is loaded. Any ideas???

Comment: @Sabha - we would have to see your full source code to understand why it doesn't work. Unfortunately description of code in human words won't suffice.

Comment: Due some confidentiality I wont be able to do that. In human words I can only say that on top of the page it accepts an url and once submit is pressed, below some statistics appears. I wanted the spinner to spin during processing. I think I have to change the window load approach and put the spinner show/hide where the php processing happens and therefore I started a new topic.

Comment: Presently the show/hide happens on window load function. Can you help me with something like the spinner should start immediately when the submit button on the form is clicked and stops when the page is fully reloaded? Thank you.

Comment: well, you only need to add the spinner object to the `body` after you click the submit button. I guess on the form's `submit` event. then of course the spinner won't exist after the page has been refreshed.

Comment: The code is working fine but not how I want it to. I completely agree with you and that is how it should happen. however, when the page starts loading (at the bottom status bar when you see "waiting for example.com") that time the spinner doesn't show up. It takes about 3-4 seconds then the spinner shows up and immediately disappears once the page is loaded. I wanted the spinner to show up during that time when the page is getting ready to load i.e. after the submit button is pressed. it doesnt change anything if i keep the window load function in head or in body. Thanks

Comment: well...hmmm your whole setup seems wrong, but might be a quick fix to use `onBeforeUnload` to add the spinner (use a flag to know when to) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload